# Did I blow my chance at an interview?

Tags: interviewing

Today, I had a phone interview at a grocery store and I guess I didn't do too bad because I was invited for a group interview for tomorrow. Bad thing is, I have to work tomorrow and I told him I couldn't attend because of work (I work a retail job). Should I just call in tomorrow? He mentioned there is another group interview next week but he didn't say what date or time. Did I blow my chances? Can I call back and tell him that i can make it after all?

Answer (score 11):

First, take a deep breath and calm down. HR Recruitment understands when a person cannot come due to schedule conflicts and won't maliciously think that you not coming tomorrow is a bad sign for them. Bear in mind though that if you don't get to this interview as soon as you can they may pick someone before they can get to you.

Call the recruitment personnel about the invitation and politely ask him on the details of next week's interview since it wasn't given.

Comment: To add to this - if the hiring manager *does* see an unwillingness to break a commitment with a current employer as a deal-breaker, that's probably not a manager that would be good to work for anyway.

Comment: Also, grocery stores tend to have a lot of employees and a lot turnover, so they are probably continually in hiring mode. You'll likely get another chance.